# Viewing CosmWasm smart contract data on a blockchain explorer

Tags: cosmos-sdk

Is it possible to view the actual data (schema data) that is stored by a smart contract?  There is a "Counter" smart contract out there and I would like to see (perhaps on a block explorer) how and where this data is stored.  I am looking to find the current state of the data (the counter) without calling "get_query" on the contract. Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer no.

Building a contract, as a developer you choose what to send as a response, you can return events, attributes and data that can be read by explorers.

If the contract in question doesn't expose the counter data as an attribute, you have no way of getting this data without doing a query on that contract.